# navbar button disfunctional after one click

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, django-forms, django-templates

I created blog forms... and suddenly I noticed a problem with Blog button in my navbar/menu bar. After one click on the Blog button it becomes dysfunctional. That is I can click on it only once.

If I type the url "..../blog" I can access the page.

I tried to add my application name before the blog.url as I some thread proposed it. It didn't work. I deleted the migrations, created the blog application again from scratch... the same think happens. I can assume it's related to the project/urls.py or the menu bar.
I retyped all codes... I still have this issue.

As always, any input is highly appreciated!

here's a Youtube short clip to better visualize my problem.
[blogButton problem](https://youtu.be/Yelk3d2gKqE)
Here are some codes in case it helps:

blog/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    PostListView,
    PostDetailView,
    PostCreateView,
    PostUpdateView,
    PostDeleteView
)
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog_index'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path("<category>/", views.blog_category, name="blog_category"),
```

project/urls.py:

```
path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    path('about/', include('about.urls'))
```

navbar.html:

Blog

```
                    <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1"><a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 js-scroll-trigger {% if request.path == contact_url %} active {%endif%}" href="{{ contact_url }}">Contact</a></li>
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
```

views.py:

```
    class PostListView(ListView):
        model = Post
        template_name = 'blog/blog_index.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
        context_object_name = 'posts'
        ordering = ['-created_on']

blog_index.html:
  ,
```